# How can I split some of the comments of a card to a new card in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I am looking a way to split specific comments (and maybe other card's elements) from an existing card to a new one.

For example, someone discovered an issue but posted it as a comment in an existing card. Then the conversation moved on, before it was decided that it belongs on a different card/list by itself.

Duplicating the card, copies all the comments (without exception) as links to the previous card, so they cannot be removed from the new card.

Is there a way to do it or it's a no-go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy a card you have the option to keep the comments, but the comments are copied, not linked, so you can copy a card with links and then remove unwanted comments from the original card. That's not ideal, but is as close as you can get at the moment.

Comment: Are you sure that the comments aren't linked? I know that I can remove those that I want from original card, but as I say at my question, I can't remove those that I don't want from the duplicated card... That's the disturbing part and the reason I opened this question. :(

Comment: Yes - I tried it before I answered - I deleted the original comments and also tried deleting the original card. The comments themselves on the copied item remain. There is a statement above the comment of the form 'A copied comment by B from card C' which links back to the original card, but the comments *themselves* are not links or linked. Nevertheless - you can't delete the duplicated ones as you say which is an oversight I feel.

Comment: So, bottom line is: I don't like your answer, as it just confirms my own research mentioned on my question, but that is like saying "not liking the truth", so I have to live with it! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is manual; but I think is the same outcome you're looking for:

1. Copy comment text
2. Create a new card
3. Paste comment text into card title &/or description
4. Copy URL of new card
5. Edit original comment, overwrite content with URL of new card

I've not been able to find an automated way of doing this, although it might be possible to write a script using the Trello API...